# Magento Compiler with multi websites

Tags: compiler, multisite

I have an instance of magento and i want to put two differents websites, so i have it :

```
**Website 1 - Store 1 - View 1**

**Website 2 - Store 2 - View 2**
```

When i put compiler on, it works on Website 1 but for Website 2 i have a blank empty page.

When i disable compiler, it works for both websites.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Have you enabled logging on both php and in magento backend. Currently your question is to open ended to answer

Comment: If you use an opcode cache like Zend OpCache or APC, this is likely more efficient than using the built-in compiler. Just an alternate solution...

Comment: Oh yes i Have opcache on my server. Thanks for the answer. But for my general culture, Why it cause this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set default page for the Website 2.

`System->Configuration->Web->CMS Home Page`

If the page is already set, then you should set 'All Store Views' in the page information block, Store View section.